# awk command to select entire record works in Terminal but not in Applescript

Tags: csv, awk, escaping, applescript, zsh

I'm trying to parse the result of a SPARQL query (CSV) in an AppleScript. The input looks like this, with each record on a new line. I just want to single out the records in their entirety (so that the user may choose between them from a list).

```
"work","expression","ecli","celex","alttitle"
"http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/85dd7fdf-45b0-4962-8c25-f3010212b52b","http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/85dd7fdf-45b0-4962-8c25-f3010212b52b.0002","ECLI:EU:C:2007:153","62006CJ0044","Gerlach"
"http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/0b70a7ef-fa45-4bbe-b76e-25d1fad10d29","http://publications.europa.eu/resource/cellar/0b70a7ef-fa45-4bbe-b76e-25d1fad10d29.0002","ECLI:EU:C:1984:63","61983CJ0046","Gerlach"
```

The output of the following `awk` command is empty in AppleScript (notice the escaped double quotes)

```
do shell script "awk 'BEGIN {RS = \"\"} { print $2 }'<<<" & quoted form of theInput
```

But when I do essentially the same in the Terminal (zsh shell), like this

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS = ""} { print $2 }' input.txt
```

I do get the first record, as expected.

Comment: The command itself should be ok; my guess would be there's something different about the input you're passing it (like maybe it has carriage returns instead of linefeeds between lines). Try something like `do shell script "cat >~/testinput.txt <<<" & quoted form of theInput`, and see what format the file is in. You can use the `file` command (e.g. `file ~/testinput.txt`) as a quick check.

Comment: `file` command tells me that it's "ASCII text, with CR, LF line terminators". But then `RS=""` should work, right?

Comment: It should, although the carriage return at the end of the line might cause trouble somewhere else, depending on how you use it. Also, I'd look at the file visually and make sure it looks right. BTW, why not just use `awk 'NR==2'` or `sed '2!d'`?

Comment: That was my first choice, too, but both of these also come up empty in the AppleScript

Comment: `do shell script "sed 's/\\r//' | awk 'NR==2 {print}'<<<" & quoted form of theInput` also gives an empty result

Comment: I'm not convinced the carriage returns are the problem (and if they were, that `sed` command won't do it -- macOS' version of `sed` doesn't support `\r`). I think there's something else that you don't realize is relevant involved. I'd try to follow the "Divide and conquer" process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and see if you can remove everything that's not absolutely needed to show the problem. Basically, remove what you think are irrelevant parts (or replace them with dummies/placeholders) bit by bit, checking to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: If you remove something you didn't think was relevant and the problem vanishes, *it was relevant*, so put it back. But then try to remove smaller bits until it's down to the absolute bare minimum. Try to get it as close as possible to just these two lines of AppleScript: `set theInput to "line 1\r\nline 2\r\nline 3\r"` and `do shell script "awk 'NR==2 {print}' <<<" & quoted form of theInput`. Those two lines work as expected when I run them in Script Editor (Result: "line 2"), so you'll need more than that to show the problem; whatever *else* remains is the source of the trouble.

Comment: @TimothyRoes Why the `<<<` redirect in the AppleScript example? Also what is currently assigned to the `theInput` variable?

Comment: @RobC Not sure why the `<<<` but it doesn't work with `<<` or `<`. And `theInput` is set to the CSV output mentioned up top.  By saving the output with `echo & theInput & > $HOME` I have now discovered that `RS` had to be set to`\r` (or rather `\\r`). Before, I use the `-o` option in `curl` but then the line breaks were LF. However, there is still one trailing end of line (`$` in `vim`) after the last field of the last record that messes things up: when I `print` that field followed by another, there's a line break between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The default record separator (RS) in awk is `\n`. Setting RS to an empty string has a special value and means the records are separated by blank lines.

To determine which type of line breaks are used in the SPARQL query results that `curl` puts out, save the output and open it with `vim -b output.txt` and do `:set list`. The `^M` denotes CR (macOS), the $ typically denotes LF (Linux). Note that using the `-o` flag in `curl` to save the output might result in different types of line breaks being used than when simply doing `echo & theVariable & > $HOME'/Desktop/output.txt'`.

Also note that a `\n` is typically added at the very end of the file (e.g. by `vim`). If the other records end with `\r` but the last one ends with `\n`, one can set `RS` to `"[\r\n]"`, which is a regex pattern for either `\r` or `\n`. In an Applescript, escaping special characters, this becomes:

```
RS=\"[\\r\\n]\"
```